# vue.config.js proxy observer socket issue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the following vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:8000'
  },
    publicPath: '/admin/',
  outputDir: '../backend/admin/'
}
```

And I'm running node application on port 8000 as a backend service,vue frontend is run with vue-cli-service serve and issue is that websocket connection for HMR is being proxied to backend.
HMR works but we are constantly getting requests to backend like:

/sockjs-node/931/f1p0xflp/websocket

How can we disable this backend calls as they are invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
ws: false
```

in vue.config.js resolved the issue